# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: with Timestamp

Tags: spring, h2, in-memory-database

**Inserting date timestamp from sql file into h2 in memory database is failing.**

I am trying to insert date from .sql file while spring application is booting.

pom.xml looks like following :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    ....
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    ....
</dependencies>
```

Properties file look like following:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:my_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    platform: h2
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: true
        format_sql: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /console
      settings:
        trace: false
        web-allow-others: false
```

Entity look like following:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "class_room"
)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Classroom
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private ZonedDateTime dateCreated = ZonedDateTime.now();

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Classroom Name can not be null!")
    private String classroomName;

    ....

}
```

while I run the application with following command:

```
mvn clean install spring-boot:run
```

I got the following error:

`Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#16f15ae9' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#16f15ae9': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/my_drive/app_server/target/classes/data.sql]:`

> **insert into class_room (id, date_created, ...) values (1, '2018-03-15 18:47:52.69', ... ); nested exception is
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex
>   character: "2018-03-15 18:47:52.69"; SQL statement**:

data.sql looks following:

```
insert into class_room (id, date_created, ... ) values (1, '2018-03-15 18:47:52.69', ... )
```

or

```
insert into class_room (id, date_created, ... ) values (1, now(), ... )
```

and 
also tried http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_timestamp

```
insert into class_room (id, date_created, ... ) values (1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ... )
```

I tried, various way of inserting the timestamp from the sql, but unfortunately sql is not able to put data into in memory database.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: P.S. If I comment out the data.sql file content, the application runs smoothly. So the problem lies in the sql. Especially how I can insert timestamp from sql into H2 database.

Comment: even with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not working

Comment: You ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue except with a string.

Comment: @virsha This is not a problem with sql. Problem is in configuration. I had same error for enumerated field. SQL is ok